# Filter dataframe based on columns without name values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe which I need to filter if the value of two columns for each row is bigger than two specific numbers. Also, it's important that I don't know anything of the dataframe except that those columns are the numbers -2 and -3

For example, we have `dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,-3,4],[5,-6,7,8]])`. Imagine that we need to filter it if the -2 and -3 columns are bigger than 0. In this case, we'll return only the first two rows.

I've tried it using `return dataframe[(dataframe[:, -3] >= 0) and (dataframe[:, -2] >= 0)]`, but it gives me the following error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select columns by positions and for `botwise and` use `&`:

```
df = dataframe[(dataframe.iloc[:, -3] >= 0) & (dataframe.iloc[:, -2] >= 0)]
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4],
                               [5,6,7,8],
                               [1,2,-3,4],
                               [5,-6,7,8]])

mask = (dataframe.iloc[:, [-3, 2]] >= 0).all(axis=1)

result = dataframe[mask]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
```